# PHP MySQL JSON UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am having trouble updating MySQL5.7.x JSON data.

I have the following JSON stored in the field activities. I want to search for activities where the outcome_id = 418

My table 2017_assessment_data has one record with student_id field (value of 3531) and the activities JSON field with the following data:

```
  {
      "course": "ENGLISH",
      "level" : "2",
      "activities": [
        {
          "comments": "test1",
          "outcomes": [
            {
              "outcome_id": "423",
              "course": "ENGLISH",
              "course_level": "2",
              "internal_outcome_id": "1"
            }
          ],
          "activity_name": "Quiz from chapters 1,2",
          "date_completed": "20180201"
        },
        {
          "comments": "test1 comments",
          "outcomes": [
            {
              "outcome_id": "421",
              "course": "ENGLISH",
              "course_level": "2",
              "internal_outcome_id": "4"
            },
            {
              "outcome_id": "415",
              "course": "ENGLISH",
              "course_level": "2",
              "internal_outcome_id": "5"
            }
          ],
          "activity_name": "Test chapter 4",
          "date_completed": "20180201"
        },
        {
          "comments": "test1",
          "outcomes": [
            {
              "outcome_id": "426",
              "course": "ENGLISH",
              "course_level": "2",
              "internal_outcome_id": "4"
            },
            {
              "outcome_id": "418",
              "course": "ENGLISH",
              "course_level": "2",
              "internal_outcome_id": "3"
            }
          ],
          "activity_name": "Activity",
          "date_completed": "20180201"
        },
        {
          "comments": "",
          "outcomes": [],
          "activity_name": "NEW",
          "date_completed": ""
        }
      ]
    }
```

I've added an empty activity at the bottom of the JSON data, but I can't later edit the values.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$update = "
    UPDATE 2017_assessment_data 

    SET

    assessment_data = JSON_SET(assessment_data,'$.activities.activity_name','NEW ACTIVITY NAME')



    WHERE 

    student_id = '3531' 
    AND 
    JSON_EXTRACT(assessment_data, '$.course') =  'ENGLISH' 
    AND 
    JSON_EXTRACT(assessment_data, '$.level') =  '2'
    AND
    JSON_EXTRACT(assessment_data, '$.activities[*].activity_name') =  'NEW'


    ";
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the MySQL JSON functions. It's a slight variation on your query:

```
UPDATE 2017_assessment_data
SET assessment_data = JSON_SET(assessment_data, TRIM('"' FROM JSON_SEARCH(assessment_data, 'one', 'NEW')), 'NEW ACTIVITY NAME')
WHERE student_id = '3531' AND 
      JSON_EXTRACT(assessment_data, '$.course') =  'ENGLISH' AND 
      JSON_EXTRACT(assessment_data, '$.level') =  '2' AND
      JSON_SEARCH(assessment_data, 'one', 'NEW') REGEXP '^"\\$\\.activities\\[[0-9]+\\]\\.activity_name"$'
```

The differences:

1. In the `WHERE` clause, we check for the existence of a `'NEW'` value using `JSON_SEARCH` and using `REGEXP` make sure that it matches the expected path.
2. In the `SET` clause, we use the same `JSON_SEARCH` to get the path to the value to be updated. Note that we have to `TRIM` the leading and trailing double-quotes from this value as they are invalid in a path string.

The easiest way to generate this query in PHP is with [HereDoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax, as it minimises otherwise necessary quoting and escaping. For example:

```
$sid = 3531;
$course = 'ENGLISH';
$level = 2;
$sql = <<<EOD
UPDATE 2017_assessment_data
SET assessment_data = JSON_SET(assessment_data, TRIM('"' FROM JSON_SEARCH(assessment_data, 'one', 'NEW')), 'NEW ACTIVITY NAME')
WHERE student_id = '$sid' AND 
      JSON_EXTRACT(assessment_data, '$.course') =  '$course' AND 
      JSON_EXTRACT(assessment_data, '$.level') =  '$level' AND
      JSON_SEARCH(assessment_data, 'one', 'NEW') REGEXP '^"\\\\$\\\\.activities\\\\[[0-9]+\\\\]\\\\.activity_name"$'
EOD;
echo $sql;
```

Output:

```
UPDATE 2017_assessment_data
SET assessment_data = JSON_SET(assessment_data, TRIM('"' FROM JSON_SEARCH(assessment_data, 'one', 'NEW')), 'NEW ACTIVITY NAME')
WHERE student_id = '3531' AND 
      JSON_EXTRACT(assessment_data, '$.course') =  'ENGLISH' AND 
      JSON_EXTRACT(assessment_data, '$.level') =  '2' AND
      JSON_SEARCH(assessment_data, 'one', 'NEW') REGEXP '^"\\$\\.activities\\[[0-9]+\\]\\.activity_name"$'
```

Comment: Works like a charm in MYSQL, but how do I get it to work in PHP?  The double quotes " are causing issues.  I tried escaping them with \ and no joy

Comment: Hi Paul, see my edit. I think that should work for you.

Comment: Awesome! Never used heredoc, but will be  :)  It works for me in PHP now.  Too bad I have to use a REGEX for this query.  Seems that MYSQL JSON functions do not like dealing with arrays of objects - updating or searching.  I could just use a TEXT field with JSON and use REGEX.

Comment: Hi Paul, I was being paranoid using a REGEXP, if you're certain you won't get a field which contains 'NEW' in it elsewhere in the JSON then you could simply change the `REGEXP ...` to an `IS NOT NULL`